# How the Java Compiler decides about the execution priorities for static and instance members/blocks

Tags: java, compiler-construction, static-members

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String str[]) {
        Hello h=Hello.INS1;
    }
}

class Hello {
 static Hello INS1=new Hello();
 static Hello INS2=new Hello(12);
{
    System.out.println("Instance Block");
}
static {
        System.out.println("Static Block");
}
private Hello() {
    System.out.println("Hello() Block");
}
private Hello(int ab) {
    System.out.println("Hello() Block");
}
}
```

A static block is always executed first but this Code is giving something which i couldn't nail in my brain.
What is actually happening here...?

OUTPUT:                                                                                            Instance Block
        Hello() Block
        Instance Block
        Hello() Block
        Static Block

Answer (score 5):

A static block is executed when the class is loaded into the JVM, and an instance block is executed when object is created.

There can be multiple static and instance initialization blocks, the order of their execution in themselves will be in the order of their appearance on a top to bottom basis.

for example consider the following code.

```
public class InitBlockExample{
    {
       System.out.println("X");
    }
    {
       System.out.println("Y");
    }
    static{
       System.out.println("A");
    }
    static{
       System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

When an object of this class is created (To show both static and instance blocks object creation is necessary) the output will be as follows:-

A
B
X
Y

the static statements also participate in order execution along with static block, and the one's those come first are executed first, this thing applies to your question here the class variables you created are static, so they will be executed first and because they require constructor execution first the constructor is executed but before the constructor all instance initialization blocks are executed so they are executed first and then constructor and in last the static block.
If you put

```
static Hello INS1=new Hello();
static Hello INS2=new Hello(12);
```

after the static block then output will be reversed and static block will be executed first.

Comment: I know what you are telling me but My code is a bit different and OUTPUT is completely different..Have a look @ the output of this code

Comment: thanks for your comment i improved my answer after your comment, hope it helps you.

Comment: Well indeed the OUTPUT is just reversed, I was missing the Static statement Concept. So thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @ Ankur Kmawat:-But i have got another doubt, I am just reading the first book on JavaSE and i read a point that to access a static variable, we dont need to instantiate the class. We can access the static variable just by using the Class Name followed by .(dot) operator followed by the variable Name. Then when i put Hello.INS1 in my main() method , WHY it is giving me error ?

Comment: It should not give any error, did you modify your program in some way,
if you did please share that and also please share the stack trace of your problem.

Comment: @AmiteshRai if you update only then anyone can help in your current problem.

Comment: With Eclipse IDE, the error thrown is: Unresolved compilation error and with cmd it shows: variable not defined/found.

Comment: @AmiteshRai on the eclipse try cleaning your project, also check any compilation errors eclipse might be showing, if doesn't work then also tell.

Comment: @AmiteshRai please share the complete stack trace of your problem, it will help in debug.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent2
{
    
    static   //static block of parent
    {
        System.out.println("im in parent staic block");
    }
    
    {    //instance block of parent
            System.out.println("im in parent instance block");
    }
    
    public Parent2()   //Parent2 constructor
    {
        System.out.println("im in Parent constructor");
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent2
{
    static  //static block of child
    {
        System.out.println("im in child staic block");
    }
    
    {   //instance block of child
        System.out.println("im in child instance block");
        
    }
    public Child2()   //Child2 constructor
    {
        System.out.println("im in child constructor");
        
    }
    
}
public class ExePriorities
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("im in main and create 1st object");
        Parent2 c1=new Child2();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("************create 2nd object********************");
        System.out.println();
        Parent2 c2=new Child2();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me how this is attempting to answer the question, nor what it conveys that the other answers here do not.

Comment: @EdGrimm the output of the above program clearly depict the execution priority of each block

Comment: @EdGrimm  first it executes the main(if there is a static block in class where main exist that will execute before main but in the above program no static block in class whr main exist) output: im in main and create 1st object im in parent static block im in child static block im in parent instance block im in parent constructor im in child instance block im in child constructor ******create 2nd object**** im in parent instance block im in parent constructor im in child instance block im in child constructor

Comment: @EdGrimm (static block executes only once bcoz they are not belongs to object static is common to all object static block executes only when class loads)

Comment: This answer would be better if it also showed what that output is, rather than requiring everyone who wanted to make use of this answer compile the code and run it themselves. Like, for example, Ankur Kumawat's answer.

Answer (score 0):

> A static block is always executed first but only after an instance
>   block,

this is false. It is true other way around.

A static block will be executed when the class is loaded and only for once.

Instance block will be executed after instance creation. The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.

Comment: yes you are right that a static block/member is executed while the compilation time only then why in this code the static member is executed last..?

Comment: @AmiteshRai can u post the output? And also note nothing is executed at the compilation time.

Comment: AhsanInstance Block
Hello() Block
Instance Block
Hello() Block
Static Block

Answer (score 0):

Static does not need any object to execute. Before creating any object the static block can execute as we are using in static method. So, here the static block is call at the time of JVM execution , means before creating the object( when first time JVM execute ). But Initialization block is   call/loaded every time when object is created.Whenever the object is created at that time the Initialization block is loaded.

[Reference post.](http://manojbardhan2009.blogspot.in/2012/10/initialization-block-vs-static-block-in.html)

Comment: @ Jdeveloper:-But i have got another doubt, I am just reading the first book on JavaSE and i read a point that to access a static variable, we dont need to instantiate the class. We can access the static variable just by using the Class Name followed by .(dot) operator followed by the variable Name. Then when i put Hello.INS1 in my main() method , WHY it is giving me error ?

Comment: No, it should not be .Because its working for me. Your code I am testing here, its running quite cool.Your implementation is correct.If you will debug the program , then you will let to know that the control steps where its going.

Comment: @ JDeveloper But unfortunately i am getting errors while compiling the code with "Hello.INS1" inside the main() method. ERRORS: Unresolved compilation problem(with Eclipse IDE) and Not a statement(with Command Prompt) at Line 3..